# How to align text below listView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So, I wanted to create a ui in flutter where I have a listView of trending animes and below it are anime names, but I'm confused how to align the names behind it.

```
SizedBox(
                  height: 250,
                  child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: [
                      for (int i = 0; i < top1Wall.length; i++)
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            child: CachedNetworkImage(
                              imageUrl: top1Wall[i]['attributes']['src'],
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: [
                      for (int i = 0; i < top1Wall.length; i++)
                        const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                            child: Text("HUEHUE",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 17.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

here is the image for reference [image: this]

Comment: are you trying to archive attached image?

Comment: huh? what do you mean I want the text 'huehue' in same position the images are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this type, you can merge two item with Column widget on ListView

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 250 + 50,
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: [
      for (int i = 0; i < top1Wall.length; i++)
        Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: top1Wall[i]['attributes']['src'],
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                child: Text("HUEHUE",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 17.0,
                        // color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          ],
        ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: yes this is correct, and you don't need to recreate another list for the names since the data  still comes from the same snapshot,

Comment: You can include height on `CachedNetworkImage` or wrap with `SizedBox` and play with sizing

Comment: Thankyou It worked out really quick